# Different definitions of highest weight representation for affine Lie algebras

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics, conformal-field-theory

In [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO8Io.png) they define highest weight representations of a Kac-Moody algebra. In [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMPAM.png) they define highest weight representations of an untwisted affine Kac Moody algebra (which can be written in the form $\hat g = g[\mathbb C(t,t^{-1})]\oplus \mathbb C \hat k\  \oplus \mathbb C L_0$, where $g$ is a semisimple Lie algebra).
I do not know how the second definition is a particular case of the second:

From [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO8Io.png):
    Let $l$ be a Kac-Moody algebra with triangular deomposition $n_-\oplus \mathfrak h\oplus n_+$.
    A *(Kac-Moody) highest weight $l$-module* with *highest weight* $\Lambda \in \mathfrak h^*$ is a $l$-module $V$ containing a nonzero vector $v\in V$ such that:
    \begin{align}
  &n_+\cdot v = 0 \\
  &H\cdot v = \Lambda(H)v\quad (\forall H \in \mathfrak h) \\
  &U(n_-)\cdot v = V 
 \end{align}
    The vector $v$ is called a *highest weight vector*.

From [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMPAM.png):
[image]

I know that we can write $\hat \lambda$ in terms of $\lambda$, $\hat\lambda (\hat k)$ and $\hat\lambda(L_0)$, so (14.121) is not surprising except in the fact that we demand $\hat\lambda(L_0)=0$. Furthermore, the writer also writes (with no justification):
[image]
However, I do not see why one is free to perform this redefinition...

---

**New Information:**
In Fuchs' book on affine Lie algebras and quantum groups, they give the following definition for highest weight representation $R_\Lambda$ of an affine Kac-Moody algebra:
$$
\begin{array}{l}{R_{\Lambda}\left(H_{0}^{i}\right) \cdot v_{\Lambda}=\bar{\Lambda}^{i} v_{\Lambda}} \\ {R_{\Lambda}(K) \cdot v_{\Lambda}=k v_{\Lambda}} \\ {R_{\Lambda}(D) \cdot v_{A}=n_{0} v_{\Lambda}}\end{array}
$$
and they say the following:

### [image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO8Io.png) Kac, V. G. (1990). Infinite-Dimensional Lie Algebras. Cam-
bridge University Press, 3 edition.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMPAM.png) Francesco, P., Mathieu, P., and Sénéchal, D. (2012).
Conformal field theory. Springer Science & Business Media.

Comment: I am a little uncertain which part is the problem. I do see that the second source is somewhat imprecise, in that they have implicitly assumed that the vector generates the representation.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft My problem is: what gives us the right to set $L_0\vert\hat\lambda\rangle=0$? (As opposed to $L_0\vert\hat\lambda\rangle=\hat\lambda(L_0)\hat\lambda\rangle$)

Comment: But how does that make sense? Is $L_0$ part of the Cartan?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft If I'm not mistaken, the Cartan is of the form $\mathfrak{g}_0\oplus\mathbb{C}\hat k\oplus\mathbb{C}L_0$.

Comment: I guess it has been too long since I studied Kac-Moody algebras, since I really don't recall this stuff. Hopefully someone else can help.

Comment: Can't you replace $L_0$ with $L_0-\alpha\hat{k}$ for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @DavidHill I don't know. Why do you think that?

Comment: If I understand notation, the element $\hat{k}$ is a two cocycle adjoined to the loop algebra of a semi-simple Lie algebra (the column space of the Cartan matrix of the KM-algebra contains a 1-dimensional isotropic subspace). The element $L_0$ is added so that there is a nondegenerate bilinear form on $\mathfrak{l}$ (as there is for a semi-simple Lie algebra & required by the KM axioms). Since $\mathbb{C}\hat{k}$ is itself isotropic before adding $L_0$ it seems like the definition of $L_0$ should have some degrees of freedom?

Comment: @DavidHill What do you mean by isotropic?

Comment: A subspace $X$ of an inner product space $V$ is isotropic if $(x,v)=0$ for all $x\in X$ and $v\in V$.